# Fix JSONResponse on listview

Tags: android, json, android-listview, arrays

I want to add row to `listview` from my `JSON` response. Here is the code from which I'm getting `JSON` and printing them in the cosole:

```
HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(
                "APIHere");
        ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);

        JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONObject searchObj = rootObj.getJSONObject("searchdata");
        JSONArray titlesObj = searchObj.getJSONArray("titles");
        JSONArray descsObj = searchObj.getJSONArray("desc");
        JSONArray linksObj = searchObj.getJSONArray("links");

        for (int i = 0; i < titlesObj.length(); i++) {
            String title = titlesObj.getString(i);
            System.out.println("Titles: " + title);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < descsObj.length(); i++) {
            String desc = descsObj.getString(i);
            System.out.println("Desc: " + desc);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < linksObj.length(); i++) {
            String link = linksObj.getString(i);
            System.out.println("Link: " + link);
        }
```

I'm iterating the whole `JSONArray` and I'm able to print those in the console. Now, I want to put these response in the listview. I'm not getting any clue regarding this.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For fetching the array items and show it into a listview:

```
ArrayList titles = new ArrayList();
ArrayList descs= new ArrayList();
ArrayList links= new ArrayList();

 for (int i = 0; i < titlesObj.length(); i++) {
        String title = titlesObj.getString(i);
        titles.add(title); 
        System.out.println("Titles: " + title);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < descsObj.length(); i++) {
        String desc = descsObj.getString(i);
        descs.add(title);
        System.out.println("Desc: " + desc);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < linksObj.length(); i++) {
        String link = linksObj.getString(i);
        links.add(title);
        System.out.println("Link: " + link);
    }
```

Next you make this arraylist a source to a listview like this:

```
   // Get a handle to the list views

//get your instance of the listview for titles

        ListView lvTitle = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
     lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>((Your activity class).this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles ));

//get your instance of the listview for descriptions

ListView lvDesc = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView02);
     lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>((Your activity class).this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, descs));

//get your instance of the listview for links

ListView lvLinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView03);
     lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>((Your activity class).this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, links));
```

### Edit

Whatever I said that should already solve your question. But, I can see that you are using the same activity to communicate to a remote server to get data. I suggest it would be best if you make a separate class for this which would return the json text `data`. Then you can call this class from your activity to get data and set the list views in your activity. It would avoid unnecessary lags and force closes in your app.

### Update

You need to implement a custom adapter for that. You need to define a single `listitem.xml` with Layouts according to your requirement. Then inflate it to the list view.

Follow this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/).

Sample Row:

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail product image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/someImage"/>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Your title-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Big Title"
    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<!-- Your subtitle -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subtitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:text="Smaller sub title" />

<!-- Rightend info -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/title"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="info"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textSize="10dip"
    android:textColor="#10bcc9"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

 <!-- Rightend Arrow -->
 <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

which would make your list row look like:

[image]

Comment: Why to use three different listview? I want to show the result in one listview, whose single row consists of title,desc and URL.

Comment: OK you should have mentioned what you need to acheive.Wait a few minutes inshallah

Comment: Tried the link which you have given. I'm getting only the last data in the lsitview. Rest of the data are not coming. Do you have any idea about this/

Answer (score 1):

```
    HttpClient hClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet hGet = new HttpGet(
            "APIHere");
    ResponseHandler<String> rHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    data = hClient.execute(hGet, rHandler);

    JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONObject searchObj = rootObj.getJSONObject("searchdata");
    JSONArray titlesObj = searchObj.getJSONArray("titles");
    JSONArray descsObj = searchObj.getJSONArray("desc");
    JSONArray linksObj = searchObj.getJSONArray("links");

    String[] a = new String[titlesObj.length()];

    String[] b = new String[descsObj.length()];

    String[] c = new String[linksObj.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < titlesObj.length(); i++) {

    String title = titlesObj.getString(i);

    a[i] = title;

     }

    for (int i = 0; i < descsObj.length(); i++) {

    String desc = descsObj.getString(i);

    b[i] = desc;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < linksObj.length(); i++) {

    String link = linksObj.getString(i);

   c[i] = link;

   }

  ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<String>();


  //if three jsonarrays having same length

  for(i=0;i<linksObj.length();i++)

   {

   al.add(" " +a[i]+" " +b[i]+""+c[i]+"");

   }

   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,al);

  ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a POJO as per your need/response you are getting

```
public class SearchData {
    private String title;
    private String Description;
    private String link;

    //getter & setter methods for each field
}
```

2.Create a `List<SearchData>` object and populate it by parsing response

```
List<SearchData> list = new ArrayList<SearchData>();
//parse JSON array to SearchData object and add it to list
list.add(searchDataObject);
```

3a. If you are willing to display a title only (i.e. if simple layout is enough)

```
ArrayAdapter<SearchData> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

** You also need to override the `toString()` method of `SearchData` POJO to return title i.e.

```
public class SearchData {
    ....
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

3b. On the other hand if you are willing to use custom layout, then your need to extend an `ArrayAdapter` and override `getView` method, then bind the new adapter the same way we did in step 3a, except this time replacing `ArrayAdapter` with custom adapter

Resources:

1 Parsing JSON response to ListView as suggested by Ram Kiran : http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

2 Customizing ListView and using Custom Adapter : http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429